# Как запустить php-fpm8.1 на ubuntu docker

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, docker, php-fpm

Установил php-fpm8.1 на ubuntu, на которой стоит еще и nginx. Хочу сделать проксирование на php-fpm8.1 чтобы заработали php файлы. Настроил порты, прописал необходимые опции в конфиге, тут приводить их не буду, вопрос не о них, да и дело не в них.

Проблема в том, что php-fpm8.1 не слушает порт, который я ему задал. То есть у меня в контейнере открыт только 80 порт от nginx и все. Команда `service php-fpm8.1 start` выводит в консоль `php-fpm8.1: unrecognized service`, хотя при команде `php-fpm8.1 -v` получаю корректный результат. Уже перерыл так много информации на эту тему, но ничего так и не нашел...

Comment: `становил php-fpm8.1 на ubuntu` это типа как на обычную убунту, без докера? `тут приводить их не буду, вопрос не о них, да и дело не в них.` - вопрос о них, дело в них... Всё это "прописывается" в докерфайл и стартует уже готовое, если вы этим пользуетесь как обычной убунту то какой смысл докер юзать?

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо за ответ, но вопрос был действительно не о них, и дело было совсем не в них. Хотя я понимаю, что это кажется очень странным и такие вопросы без приведения файлов конфигурации иногда вводят в ступор. Посмотрите на мой ответ)

Comment: На ответ нет смысла смотреть, ещё по вопросу понятно что вы докер используете не верно и не по назначению. Тут отличная аналогия это забивать гвозди микроскопом

Comment: @InDevX спасибо за ценный совет, я понял, что не правильно использую докер так как установил дистрибутив ubuntu вместо nginx. Учитывая, что я не использую volume и bind папок, теперь мне очень кайфово перезапускать контейнер каждый раз при перезапуске сервиса, когда я вношу изменения в файлы конфигурации. Но я пошел еще дальше - я удалил докер и скачал nginx для windows, кайфую. И что бы я без тебя делал

Comment: Причем тут "установил дистрибутив ubuntu вместо nginx") Можно и в 1 контейнер всё запихнуть, но это делать надо не руками через apt, а в докерфайл прописывать команды. Не желание учиться дело ваше) Правильно сделали что удалили

Comment: @InDevX не хочу учиться, хочу жениться

Comment: Есть кандидаты? Приеду на свадьбу

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Команда для установки - `apt install php8.1-fpm`, но как оно бывает с рядом других пакетов, доступно оно будет как `php-fpm8.1`, то есть не по тому имени, по которому вы загружали пакет.

Когда работа идет в докере нужно учитывать следующую особенность, если вы запускаете образ дистрибутива ubuntu и устанавливаете nginx туда, то при запуске контейнера необходимо будет запустить nginx `service nginx start`. Теперь что касается php-fpm. В большинстве источников, я повторюсь, в подавляющем большинстве, говорится о запуске и начале работы php-fpm через команду service или аналогичные ей, но в моем случае нужно было просто прописать - `php-fpm8.1` без каких либо аргументов...

В большинстве же случаев команда запустится так `service php8.1-fpm start`. Не забудьте проверить ее `service php8.1-fpm status`. Поднимать свой сервер задача не простая, столкнетесь с большим количеством подводных камней. Не забывайте редактировать по необходимости `php.ini` и не перепутайте его с `php-ini` от `php-cli`, а также загляните в `www.conf` (от php-fpm) и посмотрите настройки там. Самое важное от `www.conf` это посмотреть `user` и `user-group`, чтобы он был сопоставим с полем `user` в `nginx`. Также проверьте права на запись в файл от имени `php` и многое многое другое...

Comment: Я так и не понял при чём тут докер, если ты используешь apt.

Comment: У меня windows home

Comment: Ты запутал ещё больше.

Comment: @donRumata он внутри контейнера команды выполняет)

Comment: И внутри контейнера делает  apt install?